# Do I commit a Pull Request after each file, if I am changing multiple files?

Tags: github

I changed a file from a fork of a project on Github.  I need to commit the changes to the branch I forked.  But I have to change more than one file.  Do I make a commit after each change to each file, or is there a way to make all the changes to all the files that I am working on and commit them all at once?

I was afraid if I did them individually, it would send lots of Pull Requests and be "wrong" or a "bad" thing to do.

edit:  I'm doing this all in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm used to commit only one "thing" at the time. If you are improving a function which need to modify 4 files, I believe you should do one commit for those 4 files, and 4 commits would be unnecessary.

But if you modifiy 3 functions in 3 differents files, It's not a bad idea to make 3 separate commits. It allows a much clearer comprehension of what have been done in the log.

EDIT : Hopefully I understood you question corretly. Forgive me if I'm off topic.

Comment: How do you make all the commits at once?  I'm doing it through the browser on Github directly.

Comment: Choose the options "Upload files" in your project. You can add multiples files for a single commit :).